# Git Ignore not working, I don't get it

Tags: git, github, commit, gitignore

I thought I had figured this out but on recent attempts it is failing.

I need to commit a file, then after the commit ignore it on any subsequent repo commits.

Lets say the file is example.txt.

I commit changes to example.txt and push them to github.

I then `touch .gitignore` and add example.txt to it and save.
I then use `git rm --cached example.txt`
Then `git add .gitignore` to commit -->push it

The problem at this step is a git status is showing example.txt as deleted and thus the commit/push deletes it from the remote repo.

I have tried several variations on creating a `.gitignore` and `rm --cached`, and it either deleted the file or does not ignore it and commits unwanted changes.

Looking for insight on the exact process to ignore already committed files without deleting them.

Comment: What are you really trying to do? Why do you want files in source control that aren't local?

Comment: It is a server config file ( database) that is actually being served directly from github, but the localhost db and the remote db have diff parameters and there is no way to alter how this works unless I define two databases, I thought it would be just easier to tell git to ignore it after a first commit, and leave the remote version intact.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do realize that `git rm --cached example.txt` will remove the file from the index and keep it in the working directory alone. And then when you commit, your are committing the the deletion of the file, in addition to the `.gitignore` file that you added. Thus, when you push the file, it will be deleted from the repo.

Also, you cannot ignore changes to a tracked file using `gitignore.` You can instead try to do `git update-index --assume-unchanged example.txt` to "ignore" the file.

Comment: Thanks I think you answered first.

Comment: This definitely did the trick, but I haven't found anything explaining why the .gitignore file doesn't work in some cases. I am having trouble excluding xml files in .idea for an intellij android project. The ignore patterns are exactly as they should be and work for other directories at the same path level. why? who knows

Answer (score 2):

One possible approach is to tell Git to assume the file is unchanged.

```
$ mkdir project
$ cd project
$ touch example.txt
$ git init
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "checkin..."
$ git update-index --assume-unchanged example.txt
$ echo "hello" >> example.txt
$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
$
```

Trust that's what you want.  Be forewarned that this approach has its warts -- especially if you try to switch to a branch where the version of example.txt is different from what's in master.